# eclipse run configuration- program does not exist - but it does

Tags: eclipse, windows-xp, cygwin

just what the heck is it?
the program is there right in the projects folder. 
it cant seem to detect its own project folders debug.

i am using posix style paths for cygwin on windows. it compiles and builds the exe fine.
now it cant auto detect the exe in the projects workspace.
I had even tried adding the project folder path to the include settings. both in windows and posix style . but neither does that show up in the project explorer nor does it work.

earlier i tried using gnu style paths but the gdb didnt work.