# Eclipse SDL build error: "The program specified in the launch configuration does not exist"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've tried working some SDL on my set-up eclipse, and as I tried running it it gave me the following error:

```
  'Launching SDL.exe' has encountered a problem.
  The program specified in the launch configuration does not exist
```

I instantly went to another project to see if it builds, and it did. I also tried re-building, debugging the SDL project. I don't know if it's an error in code but just in case, this is the code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <string>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>

SDL_Surface *load_image( std::string filename ) {
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());
    if(loadedImage != NULL) {
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat(loadedImage);
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    }
    return optimizedImage;
}
```

I've googled it, and there's a duplicate question on stackOverFlow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222609/eclipse-run-configuration-program-does-not-exist-but-it-does), however it has 0 answers, not even a comment. There are no answers on google regarding this problem, so if you'd answer it, you'd probably solve hours of headaches for more people.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same problem with eclipse in Ubuntu. Spent 30 minutes and finally got it fixed as below:

- Click `Project -> Properties`;
- Select `run/debug settings`, and then the current configuration on the right pane, click `edit`;
- In the c/c++ application textbox, select `search project`, and then click the binary you want to execute for the current project.

On my system, the previous problem is due to incorrect default file name --- the linker generates `abinary.exe` but in run configuration it is "abinary".

Such tiny (but time consuming) problems should have been fixed by Eclipse developers, if they got well paid as MS or apple developers. Alas, free software?

Comment: i have a similar problem but in my case the exe file actually does not exist in the system. When i try to rebuild, eclipse says "Build Finished (took 109ms)" which is way quicker than normal but the exe file still does not get generated!

Comment: @Reubenjohn: What Yan answered was assuming that building is happening correctly. It just needs to locate the correct binary. In your case, (probably) there was an error generated during your compile which you over looked and hence the binary itself is missing. Check that once!

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your project in the Project Explorer and select `Debug As` -> `Local C/C++ Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you didn't accidentally hit a space first, when typing in the project name. Also, if on windows use CMD or Linux ls -al your workspace and look carefully at the columns of names. Try executing your .exe from the command line. If it's not there, well, look at your build output more closely! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Eclipse Neon.
In my case I was copy pasting a code to understand enumerator, but the code was faulty. As I built the project, the binaries disappeared and it said:

> the program file in launch configuration does not exist

Then I tried a simple hello world program and it still gave an error. The actual problem was that the `src` folder had both the files (I don't know how). When I deleted the other one it built and ran successfully. Hope this helped.