# OS X Eclipse C++ "Program File Does Not Exist"

Tags: c++, macos

So I've decided to give Eclipse C++ on OS X a try but a problem I'm unsure of how to solve. I loaded it up, created my project, etc. I typed some test code, to test if everything is going to run correctly:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 30;
    int b = 40;

    int sum = a + b;

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Next, is this when I try to run the code > http://prntscr.com/eai3x9

When I click the "Details" button, same text > http://prntscr.com/eai6ls

I've searched everywhere on how to fix this problem but I can't find anything. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you click on the `Details >>` button ?

Comment: Literally, it just says "Program File Does Not Exist" > http://prntscr.com/eai6ls

Comment: OK - I don't have any more ideas (not being an Eclipse user). I'd suggest using Xcode if you're going to be doing any serious C++ development on OS X, but maybe you have a reason for wanting to use Eclipse?

Comment: I do like Xcode but it's not my natural environment. I'm a native Java programmer and for the past 6 months I've thoroughly been learning C++. I wanted to start using Eclipse now my C++ is up to scratch. It's a really comfortable IDE for me which is why I want to use it.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. Just one more thing to check - I presume Eclipse needs the Xcode command line tools and that you installed these ?

Answer (score 3):

So this is what worked for me:

[Eclipse SDL build error: "The program specified in the launch configuration does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489519/eclipse-sdl-build-error-the-program-specified-in-the-launch-configuration-does)

In summary:

- go to Project > properties
- run/debug settings > current configuration > click on edit
- In c/c++ application textbox select "search project" then click on the binary you want to execute for the current project.